# Как в Python контролировать правильность вызова функции?

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции, динамическая-типизация

Я столкнулся в `Python` с такой неприятной особенностью: если я пишу вот такую функцию:

```
def multable(n):
    return [[(i + 1) * (j + 1) for j in range(0, n)] for i in range(0, n)]
```

я могу ей в качестве параметра передать всё, что угодно. Отвалится интерпретатор уже при выполнении тела функции. Это не проблема, если функция в одну строку. А как быть, если функция довольно сложная? Особенно при большой глубине вызовов, и операция, требующая строго определённого типа, оказыватся в самом конце?

Я попробовал сделать так:

```
def multable(n: int):
    return [[(i + 1) * (j + 1) for j in range(0, n)] for i in range(0, n)]
```

Интерпретатор это переваривает, но если функции передать неправильный параметр, всё равно отваливается внутри функции, а не при её вызове.

Похожая проблема есть при использовании шаблонов в C++, когда шаблон предполагает наличие определённой операции, применимой к типу, используемому в качестве фактического параметра шаблона: компилятор выдаёт ошибку внутри шаблона, а не при его использовании. С этим пытались бороться путём введения концептов, но вроде бы так и не внедрили их в язык. Но в `Python` с этим ещё сложнее, т.к. эта проблема возникает при использовании такой базовой конструкции, как функция.

А вообще, должен же быть какой-то смысл в отсутствии явно указанного типа у переменных и параметров функций, ради которого приходится мириться с подобными проблемами? Или существование `TypeScript` указывает на то, что такие решения - просто следствие лени разработчиков трансляторов? В `Makefile` тоже не указывается тип, но там это и не нужно, т.к. все переменные - строки. Но ведь `Python` - это же язык общего назначения, там одними строками не обойдёшься!

Comment: "А вообще, должен же быть какой-то смысл в отсутствии явно указанного типа" - смысл в большей гибкости и простоте написания кода. Например, это позволяет использовать утиную типизацию, а в c++, например, в тех же ситуациях приходится громоздить шаблоны и shared pointers. Всё-таки python изначально развивался как скриптовый язык с возможностью интерактивной работы с ним.

Comment: Ну вот я написал несколько сот строк на Python вчера - мне не показалось, что это просто. Просто - это Java, скорее.

Comment: А меня наоборот Java вгоняет в ужас. Это всё дело привычки.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Я попробовал сделать так:
>
> ```
> def multable(n: int):
>     return [[(i + 1) * (j + 1) for j in range(0, n)] for i in range(0, n)]
> ```
>
> Интерпретатор это переваривает, но если функции передать неправильный
> параметр, всё равно отваливается внутри функции, а не при её вызове.

Потому что это подсказка, а не указание. Этой подсказкой могут воспользоваться утилиты проверки кода и IDE. Например, `PyCharm` замечает, что функции передается другой тип.

---

Нужно проверять аргументы, например:

```
def multable(n: int):
    if not isinstance(n, int):
        raise ValueError("Ожидается n: int")

    return [[(i + 1) * (j + 1) for j in range(0, n)] for i in range(0, n)]
```

Понятно что вручную писать проверки для большого количества кода будет сложно, поэтому можно упростить это через декораторы, эта тема в [одном из обсуждений](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15299878/).

В том обсуждении нашел интересные наработки, например:

- [argtypes](https://github.com/zbo14/argtypes):

  ```
  from argtypes import argtypes

  @argtypes(arg=str)
  def expects_string(arg):
      pass

  @argtypes(arg1=int, arg2=list)
  def expects_int_and_list(arg1, arg2):
      pass

  @argtypes(arg=(float, tuple))
  def expects_float_or_tuple(arg):
      pass

  if __name__ == '__main__':
      ## ok
      expects_string('Damn good coffee!')
      expects_int_and_list(8, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7])
      expects_float_or_tuple(0.1)
      expects_float_or_tuple((0, 1))
  ```
- [beartype](https://github.com/beartype/beartype):

  ```
  >>> @beartype
  ... def spirit_bear(kermode: str, gitgaata: (str, int)) -> tuple:
  ...     return (kermode, gitgaata, "Moksgm'ol", 'Ursus americanus kermodei')
  >>> spirit_bear(0xdeadbeef, 'People of the Cane')
  ```

---

**PS.** Тут привел только часть найденного, поэтому уверен, что можно еще кучу интересного найти

Comment: argtypes - полезный модуль, возьму на заметку)

Comment: Мне больше понравился `beartype`, более аккуратно получается по синтаксису. Вот: https://gist.github.com/leycec/3d48cc60e7d5fe8860b077acb067dc54#file-beartype-py

Comment: Для beartype возможно имеет смысл дать ссылку на github: https://github.com/beartype/beartype

Comment: @insolor, спасибо, согласен :)

Answer (score 2):

`Type annotations` aka `type hints` - это фича, которая в python носит исключительно вспомогательный характер и не даёт никакого эффекта на выполнение кода и, тем более, не может служить для типизации переменных. По большей части это инструмент дебагинга (PyCharm вроде, даже умеет с ними работать) на оценочном уровне.
Явное объявление типов параметров функции в python просто не имеет смысла:

```
def aa(bbb=[]):
    print(bbb)

ccc=3
aa(ccc) #3
```

Поэтому всегда имеет смысл ставить "защиту от дурака" и проверять явно проверять передаваемые функции параметры. Плюс, на этапе дебагинга (но не в продакшне) помогает `assert`

Answer (score 1):

Указание типа переменной, которую передают в функцию (n: int) ,  лишь показывает программисту какой тип она ожидает, чтобы тот не пихал в неё строки или ещё что. Если вы боитесь что в функцию могут попасть не только целые числа, но и другие типы, то делайте проверку