# Строгая нотация типов в python

Tags: python, python-3.x, типизация

Задавал как то вопрос про нотации типов в функциях в python в стиле

```
def incr(number: int) -> int:
    return number + 10
```

В таком случае, работая в IDE я буду получать соответствующие подсказки типов, по сути информируя среду о типах данных, с которыми работаю. И мне известно, что в отличии от условного с++, принимаемый на вход тип данных может не соответствовать тому что указан в нотации, IDE может и что-то скажет об этом, но сам интерпретатор никаким образом ругаться не станет. Вопрос вот в чём:

**Существуют ли библиотеки с декораторами(?), автоматизирующую проверку типов, и вызывающие исключения, в случае несоответствии проверки?**

Выражаясь псевдоязыком, в моей голове это должно выглядеть так:

```
def incr(number: int) -> int:
    assert isinstance(number, int), TypeError
    result = number + 10
    assert isinstance(result, int), TypeError
    return result
```

Только разумеется, я имею в виду автоматизацию процедуры проверки всех принимаемых и возвращаемых значений

Comment: Какое-нибудь `def func(x: MyProto[T]) -> Callable[[], MyProto[MyProto[T]]]` проверить в рантайме как минимум сильно нетривиально, если вообще возможно

Comment: У меня подозрение, что такие библиотеки не очень будут идеологии языка соответствовать. Вы фактически динамическую типизацию отменить хотите:-)  Но есть Mypy, как, вероятно, знаете. "Это статический анализатор типов для Python, который позволяет находить ошибки несоответствия типов в коде. Mypy выводит ошибку, если при работе с аннотациями типов значение переменной не соответствует присвоенному ей типу." (цитата с tproger.ru)

Comment: @Сергей mypy работает не в рантайме и не вызывает исключения

Comment: Я знаю. Это на всякий случай для полноты ответа. Я сомневаюсь, что есть такая штука полноценная для рантайма.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Как в Python контролировать правильность вызова функции?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/918864/1365)

Answer (score 4):

Есть библиотека [typeguard](https://github.com/agronholm/typeguard) (вроде бы слышал про нее раньше, но сейчас нашел через [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57813576/4752653)), которая умеет, в том числе добавлять проверки типов получаемых и возвращаемых значений функций.

[Пример из документации](https://typeguard.readthedocs.io/en/latest/userguide.html#using-the-decorator):

```
from typeguard import typechecked

@typechecked
def some_function(a: int, b: float, c: str, *args: str) -> bool:
    ...
    return retval

@typechecked
class SomeClass:
    # All type annotated methods (including static and class methods and properties)
    # are type checked.
    # Does not apply to inner classes!
    def method(x: int) -> int:
        ...
```

Мой пример:

```
from typeguard import typechecked


@typechecked
def test(x: int) -> int:
    return x


print(test(10))  # Выведет 10
print(test("abcd"))  # TypeError: type of argument "x" must be int; got str instead
```

В том числе умеет проверять, например, что передан список целых чисел, а не произвольных значений:

```
from typing import List

from typeguard import typechecked


@typechecked
def test(x: List[int]) -> int:
    return sum(x)


print(test([1, 2, 3, "A"]))  # TypeError: type of argument "x"[3] must be int; got str instead
```

---

Похожая библиотека: [strongtyping](https://github.com/FelixTheC/strongtyping), работает похожим образом (правда, не умеет проверять тип возвращаемого значения):

```
from strongtyping.strong_typing import match_typing


@match_typing
def test(x: int) -> int:
    return x


print(test("abcd"))
# Incorrect parameter: [x] `'abcd'`
#         required: <class 'int'>
```

```
from strongtyping.strong_typing import match_typing
from typing import List

@match_typing
def test(x: List[int]) -> int:
    return sum(x)

print(test([1, 2, 3, "A"]))
# Incorrect parameter: [x] `[1, 2, 3, 'A']`
#         required: typing.List[int]
```

---

Библиотека [beartype](https://github.com/beartype/beartype). Умеет проверять тип аргументов и тип возвращаемого значения:

```
from beartype import beartype


@beartype
def test(x: int) -> int:
    return x + 1


print(test("abcd"))
# beartype.roar.BeartypeCallHintParamViolation: @beartyped test() parameter x='abcd' violates type hint <class 'int'>, as 'abcd' not instance of int.
```

```
from beartype import beartype


@beartype
def test_return(x: int) -> int:
    return "abcd"


print(test_return(1))
# beartype.roar.BeartypeCallHintReturnViolation: @beartyped test_return() return 'abcd' violates type hint <class 'int'>, as 'abcd' not instance of int.
```

Но проверка типа вложенных значений в списках работает как-то странно. Если вложенные значения одного типа, но не того, какой указан в аннотации, то ошибка вылетает:

```
@beartype
def test_int_list(x: List[int]) -> int:
    return sum(x)


test_int_list(["A", "D", "d"])
# beartype.roar.BeartypeCallHintParamViolation: @beartyped test_int_list() parameter x=['A', 'D', 'd'] violates type hint typing.List[int], as list index 1 item 'D' not instance of int.
```

А если передать список смешанного типа, то `beartype` такое пропускает, и ошибка вылетает уже в самой функции:

```
@beartype
def test_int_list(x: List[int]) -> int:
    return sum(x)


test_int_list(["A", 1, 2])
#     return sum(x)
# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'
```

Comment: typeguard - очень медленная библиотека, написаная с нарушениями PEP 8 и с применениями медленного модуля ast, решение с декоратором typeguard в 2 раза медленнее, чем декоратор static из моего ответа. Вот результаты тестов: # timeguard: 16.53926372528076
# static: 2.73103404045105

Comment: В проде такую ересь использовать не будут

Comment: @Kram, никто не мешает поставить декоратор только на "входных" методах, где приходят данные извне, тогда разница в производительности будет минимальна. `В проде такую ересь использовать не будут` - ну, более-менее покрытое тестами и выложенное на pypi готовое решения я бы с большей уверенностью стал использовать, чем написанное за полчаса на коленке решение со стековерфлоу) Давайте смотреть на вещи здраво, а не раскидываться оценочными суждениями)

Comment: Заглянул в код typeguard, не увидел там каких-то жестких нарушений PEP8. Может они там есть, но проблемы с PEP8 решаются прогонкой через какой-нибудь форматтер (если речь о форматировании).

Comment: P.S. ну и у typeguard все-таки больше функциональность, например, он умеет с дженериками работать в отличие от вашего решения  (как минимум в достаточной для практического применения степени, сильно глубоко не копал) .

Comment: "ну, более-менее покрытое тестами и выложенное на pypi готовое решения" - даже не выложенное на pypi, допустим это не показатель. Но в любом случае есть какая-то видимая история разработки и покрытие тестами.

Comment: Ок, хорошо, я тогда доделаю своё решение и выложу библиотеку на pypi, а дальше сделаем тесты и выбирем лучшую библиотеку.

Comment: @Kram если цель сделать хорошую годную библиотеку - без проблем, почему бы и нет, делайте. Если цель кому-то доказать, что ваше решение самое лучшее - это не, на что стоит тратить свою жизнь. "сделаем" - не знаю, с чего вы решили, что я буду в этом участвовать)

Comment: Нет конечно, цель сделать хорошую библиотеку

Answer (score 3):

Python - динамически типизированый язык, максимум можно сделать типа такого костыля:

```
from typing import get_type_hints


def static(func):
    def wrapper(*args):
        typehints = list(get_type_hints(func).values())
        with_return = False
        if len(args) > len(typehints):
            raise SyntaxError('invalid syntax.')
        elif len(args) < len(typehints):
            typehints = typehints[:-1]
            with_return = True
        else:
            pass
        for i in args:
            for j in typehints:
                if not isinstance(i, j):
                    raise TypeError(f'{j} type is not {i} type')
        if with_return:
            return func(*args)
        else:
            func(*args)

    return wrapper
```

Но данный декоратор обязывает человека использовать тайпхинты, плюс у него есть ещё пара минусов.