# Python декоратор для проверки типов

Tags: python, типы, декоратор

Я читаю книгу Дэвида Близи "Python. Книга рецептов" и там приводится пример декоратора, в аргументы которого передаются типы декорируемой функции и он их проверяет в момент вызова, если тип не указан, то он считается любым. Можно использовать kwargs, если надо указать тип после пропущенного. Код прикладываю:

```
import inspect
from functools import wraps


def typeassert(*ty_args, **ty_kwargs):
    def decorate(func):
        if not __debug__:
            return func
        sig = inspect.signature(func)
        bound_types = sig.bind_partial(*ty_args, **ty_kwargs).arguments
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            bound_values = sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
            for name, value in bound_values.arguments.items():
                if name in bound_types:
                    if not isinstance(value, bound_types[name]):
                        raise TypeError(
                            f'Argument {name} must be {bound_types[name]}'
                        )
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorate


@typeassert(int, str, z=float)
def foo(a, b, c, z):
    return f'{a}, {b}, {c}, {z}'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(foo(1, 'bar', [], 4.0))
```

Всё работает отлично, за исключением одного момента, если попробовать применить данный декоратор к методам какого-либо класса, то он будет некорректно работать, поскольку считает первый параметр self или cls. Для выхода из данной ситуации я пока придумал два метода решения:

1. Можно передавать все аргументы, как kwargs, что не очень удобно.
2. Унаследовать класс от какого-то "класса-затычки", и передавать в первый аргумент тип класса родителя, что также не самый удобный вариант по многим причинам, к тому же, работать для класс методов второй способ не будет.

Так вот, сам вопрос, можно ли как-то изменить возвращаемый объект класса inspect, чтобы удалить первый элемент(self или cls). Немного изучив данную библиотеку я не нашёл никого способа это сделать, хотя я не отрицаю, что мог его пропустить.

Comment: Можно вручную убирать первый элемент: `bound_values = sig.bind(*args[1:], **kwargs)`

Comment: Ну или из возвращаемого объекта удалять первый элемент, без разницы. В любом случае не обязательно в сам inspect влазить, достаточно входные или выходные данные модифицировать.

Comment: Проблема в том, что объект типа Inspect является неизменяемым, я бы с радостью применил на него срез. А если пытаться изменить его далее, изменяя словарь объекта bound_types, то это решение будет работать, но оно будет достаточно костыльным, к тому же скорее всего уязвимым. Поэтому, как мне кажется, если каким-то образом убрать первый элемент объекта sig, то в дальнейшем проблем быть не должно.

Comment: Меняйте args, см. первый комментарий, тут никаких проблем не будет. Про уязвимость не знаю что вы имеете в виду. По поводу костыльности - ну сам по себе такой способ указания типов довольно костыльный, при том что есть аннотации типа для этого, и есть даже готовые библиотеки, которые по ним в рантайме могут типы проверять.

Comment: См. тут примеры: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1397669/1365

Comment: То что вы предложили в первом комментарии работать не будет, я проверял, поскольку bound_values - это аналог словаря, где к каждому аргументу приписаны значения которые были переданы в метод. Где далее в цикле эти значения берутся и сравниваются с типами, которые были получены по сигнатуре функции(bound_types), и поскольку в этой сигнатуре присутствовал cls/self, то он забирает на себя первый указанный тип, что далее просто рейзит ошибку, поскольку на самом деле этот тип должен быть присваиваться другой переменной.